# Cache streaming video on an iphone

Tags: iphone, video-streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am looking for some ideas regarding the caching of the streaming video from my server.

Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not cache m3u8 streams on the iphone device itself. You can use progressive download of mp4 videos while playing. Once the progressive download is done, you may then play the file/s locally from the device -> local caching.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. :)

May i knw how to apply progressive downloading??

Comment: I am looking for the same solution. Could you provide a code example or some hints about achieving it?